# How to add custom emoji to slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to add custom emoji to all workspaces that use my bot.
According to [SLACK API](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.emoji.add), I can do it, but workspaces need to have an Enterprise Grid plan, which is unfree.
So am interested in another way of solving this issue.
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

It is only available for subscriptions https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/206870177-Add-customised-emoji-and-aliases-to-your-workspace